# Mask & Unmask websocket data in python

Tags: python, websocket, mask

I'm trying to create a python websocket class that can connect to a websocket server and I need help writing a function that can mask and unmask data. I have an similar websocket class in PHP that looks like this:

```
function unmask($text) {
$length = ord($text[1]) & 127;
if($length == 126) {
    $masks = substr($text, 4, 4);
    $data = substr($text, 8);
}
elseif($length == 127) {
    $masks = substr($text, 10, 4);
    $data = substr($text, 14);
}
else {
    $masks = substr($text, 2, 4);
    $data = substr($text, 6);
}
$text = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
    $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
}
return $text;
```

}

```
function mask($text){
$b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
$length = strlen($text);

if($length <= 125)
    $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
    $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
elseif($length >= 65536)
    $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
return $header.$text;
}
```

So I tried to create the same thing in Python:

```
def mask(text):
    b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f)
    length = len(text)

    if length <= 125:
        header = struct.pack('CC', b1, length)
    if length > 125 & length < 65536:
        header = struct.pack('CCn', b1, 126, length)
    if length <= 65536:
        header = struct.pack('CCNN', b1, 127, length)
    return header + text
```

And it returns an error:

> Bad char in struct format

If anyone could help me write the function that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: In your python you dont use `elif` when you use `elseif` in php.

Comment: @PaulRooney I didn't... I used if all the way.

Comment: Also php `elseif($length >= 65536)` python `if length <= 65536:`. Did you want those `<=` `=>` to be different?

Comment: @PaulRooney Oh, length <= 65536 should be length >= 65536 but that doesn't fix the problem. Still says 'bad char in struct format'.

Comment: In format string for php `C`=unsigned char, `n`=unsigned short, `N`=unsigned long in python `B`=unsigned char, `H`=unsigned short, `L`=unsigned long.

Comment: @PaulRooney Yes, but not with my my own code i found another code here: http://sidekick.windforwings.com/2013/03/minimal-websocket-broadcast-server-in.html.

Comment: If you have an answer why not post it?

Comment: @PaulRooney I don't know :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an really helpful script that did exactly what i needed.

> http://sidekick.windforwings.com/2013/03/minimal-websocket-broadcast-server-in.html

Comment: You won't get much rep posting links. You'd be better off posting the actual code in your answer:)